# Comparing Directed Unweighted Graphs with a Dissimilar Number of Nodes

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, similarities, graph-theory

I'm looking to compare 2 unweighted directed graphs and get an (ideally differentiable) similarity score. Both graphs describe a trajectory in a 2d space.

The *reference graph* is a step by step guide to an end location. The nodes have a value which corresponds to a precise action such as forward 1m, left 30 degrees. The edges are only used to link steps together.

The *comparison graph* nodes on the other hand only contain directions rather than precision instructions (e.g. left, right, forward). Similarly the edges have no information.

While both graphs contain similar information,the *comparison graph* contains far fewer points (2-10x). I first tried reducing the *reference graph* to the same direction level by compressing multiple nodes of the same value together. This works somewhat, but leaves a lot to be desired. It is still too "low-level" to be directly comparable.

I'm in the process of evaluating edit distance (specifically a [soft variant](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.12562#:%7E:text=Soft%20edit%20distance%20for%20differentiable%20comparison%20of%20symbolic%20sequences,-Evgenii%20Ofitserov%2C%20Vasily&text=Edit%20distance%2C%20also%20known%20as,sequences%20and%20natural%20language%20processing.)) and [nDTW](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53250/normalized-measure-from-dynamic-time-warping#:%7E:text=The%20dynamic%20time%20warping%20gives,which%20demonstrates%20the%20dis%2Dsimilarity.) as possible candidates.

My questions are:

1. What other metrics exist to compare graphs of this nature? I've looked at some [slides](http://www.cs.uoi.gr/%7Epvassil/downloads/GraphDistance/LauraZager.pdf) and a [survey on graph comparison](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-53708-y.pdf) and while these were helpful, I don't have enough intuition to choose between the methods they propose.
2. Are there other ways of comparing these 2 sequences, besides treating them as graphs?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/487815/2921, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/130245/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3831049/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is meant by directions or precise actions or precision instructions or what distinctions you are drawing between them.   You haven't listed any requirements for comparing the two graphs, nor described them in a clear way, nor described their semantics, so I'm not sure how we are supposed to provide an answer or evaluate proposed answers.  If you're looking for brainstorming, that's not what this site was designed for.